# Issues with splitter on discone receiving antenna

Tags: antenna

I need to connect my discone antenna to 2 LTR-SDR USB devices on different PCs (One a PIAware raspberry pi and the other a PC running WIndows 10). Am I going to experience any issues doing this? Such as a weak signal on one or both SDRs?

Comment: Depends on how much the loss is in the splitter, and what your SNR requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

> *Am I going to experience any issues doing this? Such as a weak signal
> on one or both SDRs?*

An antenna receives power and, that power produces a voltage signal into a controlled impedance like 50 Ω so, if you want to use two receivers, each with a 50 Ω input impedance, then the power received is split between them and you lose 3.01 dB of signal to each receiver.

In addition, you need some kind of power splitter that can separate the input signal into two half-power signal outputs. This needs to be matched to whatever impedance system your antenna and receivers use (typically 50 Ω) but, might comes with a small additional cost of 1 or 2 dB power loss.